# Woocommerce + WCMP list all subscriptions data per vendor

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, marketplace, vendor

WooCommerce Marketplace (WCMP) is a multivendor plugin for woo. In my PHP API I'm building, I need to iterate all vendors like this to get subscriber & product data per vendor (Psuedo-code):

```
foreach($vendors as $vendor){
    $vendorsActiveSubscriptions = get_wcmp_active_subscriptions($vendor);
    foreach($vendorsActiveSubscriptions as $subscription){
        echo $vendor->userId;
        echo $subscription->product_name;
        echo $subscription->userId; // of customer
        echo $subscription->product_categories;
    }
}
```

I realize it won't be quite as simple as that but you see what I'm after. Having trouble finding docs that will lead me to doing it without a bunch of manual database queries.